# How can I get back a deleted answer that I found helpful?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

My question [Mapping of YAWL onto BPMN and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59579663/) targets a YAWL-specific issue. I was in contact with the YAWL foundation, convinced them to post an answer on SO, but the very helpful answer disappeared, I assumed because of downvotes by the reviewers.

Can somebody help me to retrieve the text? I guess, it did not help that I edited it to make an answer which is not link-only. It might even have been mistaken as spam, although the name of the user discloses the source clearly.

The deleted answer:

> [image]

As text, so links are available:

> I would also like to point you to Apromore and [a related discussion in the YAWL User Group Forum](http://www.yaug.org/node/600):
>
> 1. There is an [XSD file that specifies the YAWL XML format](https://github.com/yawlfoundation/yawl/blob/master/schema/YAWL_Schema4.0.xsd)
> 2. There is a tool called [apromore](https://apromore.org/) which converts BPMN or other formats into the YAWL XML format.

Comment: It was likely deleted as SPAM, since they failed to disclose their association with the links they had posted.

Comment: @yivi - I think that was the issue [I edited my question to account for that]. Still - I would love to have the link they posted.

Comment: Is it possible to undelete the answer (and edit-in the disclosure statement)? As I said, I mailed those guys, and convinced them to join SO, and they are just a bunch of researchers without interest in spamming.

Comment: The answer was deleted by a moderator, probably in response to a flag. The best way to have it undeleted is for the author to edit to disclose their affiliation with the links, and then flag so a  moderator can review the edit. Also, they should flesh out the answer so it consists in something more than links. Link-only answers are also subject to being flagged and deleted.

Comment: @yivi I tried to do the fleshing-out for them, but the flaggers were faster :-/ I hope the account is still available (and they are not black-listed or something). Could you help me out with a profile-link to them, please?

Comment: It looks like https://stackoverflow.com/users/12843693/yawl-usergroup is indeed blocked, or are they?

Comment: Your original question in main seems to be a request for off-site resources. I'm not convinced it should remain open.

Comment: Well, a list of non-mappable items on both sides (YAWL, BPMN) would be an answer to my question without off-site resources. It would be kind if you at least don't delete it. [I edited my question on main SO]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method to get it done quickly is to go to [SO close vote reviews chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and ask there. With some luck there are enough high rep users with domain knowledge about the topic present, in order to cast the necessary undelete votes.

Otherwise, you could post on meta like you did now and request for the post to get undeleted.

As for the specific case, your answer was deleted because it was little more than a link to an external site. Such answers are discouraged and considered very low quality, since links tend to die over time and answers should provide content here on this site.

If you wish to link to off-site content, then provide some explanation/examples etc here as well, or quote relevant parts instead of just linking them - just like the new answer you posted does.

Comment: Note: it wasn't "their" answer. But an answer posted to a question of theirs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the text of the deleted answer:

> I would also like to point you to Apromore and [a related discussion in the YAWL User Group Forum](http://www.yaug.org/node/600):
>
> 1. There is an [XSD file that specifies the YAWL XML format](https://github.com/yawlfoundation/yawl/blob/master/schema/YAWL_Schema4.0.xsd)
> 2. There is a tool called [apromore](https://apromore.org/) which converts BPMN or other formats into the YAWL XML format.

There were also these comments under the answer:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25272940)

And

> Welcome to SO! I edited your answer so that it follows [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)